# Function is not defined | Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I have **boleto.js**

```
var axios = require('axios');    
function getBoleto (token) {
  if (!token) throw Error('Miss Token!');

  return axios.get(
    '/boletos',
    {
      params: {
        token: 'token...'
      }
    }
  ).then(res => {
    //console.log(res.data);
    return res.data;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error boletos', err);
    })
}        
getBoleto()
  .then(boletos => {
    gravar(boletos, function(err){
        if (err) throw new Error('Error boletos');
    });
  });
```

And **gravar.js**

```
module.exports = function (object, callback) {
// Save DB
...
console.log('Saved successfully');
callback();
}
```

What I need? Save the return of boleto.js in gravar.js

But brought this message :  Reference error: gravar is not defined

Comment: you still need to var gravar = require('./gravar.js') to be able to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **boleto.js** you need to add:

```
var gravar = require('./gravar.js');
```

If **gravar.js** is in other directory, provide correct relative path.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful about error message "function X is not defined". My experience in Chrome was painful, because in realy, the function has always been defined. What occured is that there was an error within the function, but message was hiding it.

Comment: it would help if you could be explicit about what error there was in the function. i do not see how gravar would be defined within boleto.js, so it looks to me as if gravar might not be defined.

Comment: I do not refered about boleto.js function, but to a bad signaling in Chrome inspector message. Inside my function there was some undefined variables, but inspector signalized the error as function undefined. Just a message that may confund the debugging.